# valac generating bad C code on DBus program

Tags: dbus, vala

Can someone spot the problem with this code?
It is compiling with valac but I get an error when gcc tries to compile the C code generated by valac, here's the gcc output:

```
(...) Weather.c: En la función ‘__lambda3_’:
(...) Weather.c:696:9: aviso: la asignación descarta el calificador ‘const’ del tipo del destino del puntero [activado por defecto]
(...) Weather.c: En la función ‘address_proxy_get_address’:
(...) Weather.c:1535:228: error: ‘error’ no se declaró aquí (primer uso en esta función)
(...) Weather.c:1535:228: nota: cada identificador sin declarar se reporta sólo una vez para cada función en el que aparece
```

Here's the DBus interface declaration:

```
[DBus (name="org.freedesktop.Geoclue.Address")]
interface Address : Object {
    public abstract void get_address (out int32 timestamp, out HashTable<string,string> address, out Accuracy acc);
    public signal void address_changed (int32 timestamp, HashTable<string,string> address, Accuracy acc);
}

struct Accuracy {
    int32 int1;
    double double1;
    double double2;
}
```

Comment: Where's the function `address_proxy_get_address` declaration? It's complaining about that function, and not what you're showing.

Answer (score 1):

Methods for D-Bus proxies need to throw an exception:

```
public abstract void get_address (out int32 timestamp, out HashTable<string,string> address, out Accuracy acc) throws GLib.IOError;
```